# Exporting an uploaded map from Google Earth Engine to my drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I uploaded a map which I created of miombo woodland and added it to the Hansen gfc map layer with the idea being to export my map to my drive merged with gfc layers however I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Image.clipToBoundsAndScale, argument 'input': Invalid type. 
Expected type: Image<unknown bands>. Actual type: FeatureCollection. (Error code: 3)
```

This is my code:

```
var miombo_woodland = ee.FeatureCollection("users/mafuruse8097/miombo_woodland");
Map. addLayer(table);
var areaCover = treeCover.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
                .divide(1000000).select([0],["table"]);

var areaLoss = loss.gt(0).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).multiply(treeCover)
              .divide(1000000).select([0],["table"]);

var areaGain = gain.gt(0).multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).multiply(treeCover)
              .divide(1000000).select([0],["table"]);
var table = table.filter(ee.Filter.or());
            
// Sum the values of loss pixels.
var statsLoss = areaLoss.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  collection: table,
  scale: 10
});

// Sum the values of gain pixels.
var statsGain = areaGain.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  collection: table,
  scale: 10}); 
  

// Export the image, specifying the CRS, transform, and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: table,
  description: 'miombo_woodland',
  scale: 10,
  region: table
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tell you the answer. You use `Export.image.toDrive` but pass it a `FeatureCollection` instead of an `Image`.

Try [`Export.table.toDrive`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-table-todrive) instead:

> **Export.table.toDrive**
>
> Creates a batch task to export a FeatureCollection as a table to Drive.